# Show that $GL_{n}(F)$ is non-abelian for any $n \geq 2$ and any $F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Show that $GL_{n}(F)$ is non-abelian for any $n \geq  2$ and any $F$.

(From Dummit's Abstract Algebra)

Now it says $GL_{n}(F)$ is an n by n matrix with entries from F and must be invertible (the determinant is non zero), with matrix multiplication as its binary operation. Non-abelian means that the group elements do not commute under the operation, that is $A \star B \neq B \star A$, which is generally the case for a matrix multiplication. But the question says ANY matrix larger than 2 by 2, with ANY entries as long as the matrix is invertible.

But aren't non-zero diagonal matrices part of the general linear group? Because surely their elements are in F, and surely their determinant is non zero, and surely they commute! What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh my god, does the word "any" mean like I could choose just any n and F, so need I just show one example of non-commutation??

Comment: Yes, there only needs to be one example of non commutative matrices for each $n \geq 2$ to make that group non abelian.

Comment: I now see my misunderstanding, thanks!

Comment: It might help to recall that a group is abelian if *every* pair of elements commute. The negation of this statement says that a group is non-abelian if there exists at least one pair that does not commute (but some elements, as you point out with your diagonal example, may commute).

Answer (score 5):

You just need to find *two* matrices that don't commute.

\begin{gather}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}

For $n\ge2$ just take these as the upper left block and complete with ones on the diagonal and zero elsewhere. The coefficients at $(1,1)$ are different.

Comment: so I guess it was just sufficient to give one example of non-commutation to ensure the non-abelian nature of the group. Thanks

Comment: @VladeKR Yes, two particular matrices *may* commute. For the general case I added a hint.

Answer (score 1):

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+I$,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+I$, $AB \ne BA$.

Comment: Usually $GL$ denotes the invertible matrices.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for catching that, I had meant to add the identity.